# adjust extensions for imports in Jest/Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs

Can't find a way to specify extensions for imported files for babel-jest. I have a test file, where Index has a `.jsx` extension:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Message from 'src/Index';

describe('#test', () => {
```

By webpack I can do it so:

```
'resolve': {
  'extensions': ['.jsx']
},
```

How I can define it for Jest?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I'd guess the issue is probably a missing jest.unmock or similar not a babel related issue.

Comment: Sorry for delay. The error has occurred during the build. `Error: Cannot find module 'src/Index' from 'test.js'`. I can solve that problem by changing an extension to `.js`